# Has anyone ever seen this error from Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My Heroku app is crashing and the only error it's showing in the logs is:

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" 
host=subdomain.domain.com request_id=123b1c52-a7ba-4160-9a03-5fab52e590e4 
fwd="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= 
protocol=http
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've encountered this before... While there are a lot of potential reasons, the most common is that environment variables aren't appropriately set in Heroku. Go to your Heroku App, Settings, Reveal Config Vars.

Add things like S3, Twilio, Etc. variables here...

Comment: This was it... I was missing various keys... opps!

Answer (score 0):

Heroku dyno crashed. Consider to restart your dyno.

Ref: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h10-app-crashed

Comment: Yes - Restarted Multiple Times